# Getting low accuracy on two fields after labelling using the tool, Form Recognizer, Custom Label

Tags: computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I need help with recognition of two particular fields- credit date and credit type. Getting low accuracy (training ~30%) after labelling and even lower on the test set (~10%).

I am using Custom Label API after labelling, tagging and training.

I think as these two fields appear at different places relative to other fields due to different number of entries in different receipts.

Is there anything I can do to improve these fields' accuracy.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cognitive Services [Form Recognizer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/) service has added support for new and exciting features - multiple forms models (model compose), language expansion, pre-built business cards model, selection marks and lots more are now available in the Form Recognizer v2.1 release.

Form Recognizer [sample labeling tool](https://fott-preview.azurewebsites.net/) has been updated to support the new release functionality, see this [quick start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/label-tool?tabs=v2-1) for getting started with custom train with labels.

Please find the snapshot for the JSON for the image that you are trying.

[image]